# How to call a function when using a map constructor?

Tags: c++

I found this code at [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/).  How does the compiler know to use the function defined in classcomp?

struct/function

```
struct classcomp 
  {
  bool operator() (const char& lhs, const char& rhs) const
    {
    return lhs<rhs;
    }
  };
```

Map Construction

```
  map<char,int,classcomp> fourthm;
```

Constructor Prototypes from link above:

```
explicit map ( const Compare& comp = Compare(),const Allocator& = Allocator() );

template <class InputIterator> map ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last,const Compare& comp = Compare(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );

map ( const map<Key,T,Compare,Allocator>& x );
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B

Comment: so the function call operator is over-loaded

Comment: Your example give uses classcomp()...while the example aboe gives classcomp...which one is correct

Comment: @Chris : They both are, in different contexts. His example is instantiating the type to use it, your example is merely specifying the type as a template argument (and the call to the `map` constructor implicitly instantiates it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses the default-constructor for classcomp class so you get an object that has operator() defined and acts like a function.

Comment: so the function call operator is over-loaded

Comment: Anything that you can apply the function call operator to is a functor. A function is a functor, an object of a class type with `operator()` is a functor, an object that has a conversion to a pointer to a function is a functor.

Comment: Why is there no () in the example i provided?  There is in the example that Dave provided

Comment: @Chris : There is -- it's in the `map` constructor arguments, `const Compare& comp = Compare()`.